# Changing Registry Values with Ruby/JRuby

Tags: ruby, registry

I have a .reg file that changes some registry values and this works just fine. I'm trying to call that from a script written in JRuby with a `system('path\to\file.reg')` call, but for some reason the file is not getting executed. I've tried using double quotes instead of single quotes, two forward slashes to avoid escaping, backslashes, and several other things. I've also tried to programmatically change the registry values in my script by using the Win32API from Ruby, but I've had no such luck there either (it is a 64-bit machine). Code I used was:

```
Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.open('SOFTWARE\foo') do |reg|
    reg.each_value { |name, type, data| } 
end
```

Are there any other ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by running the IDE as an administrator and running the following command:

```
system("reg add HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Path\\To\\Location /v *Name* /t REG_SZ /d *Data* /f")
```

Basically, I executed the contents of the .reg file through the system call since it only did one thing anyway.